# Roboto font not loading with materialize-sass gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, materialize

Although materialize seems to load properly, the Roboto font is not applied. Any clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was loading normalize afterwards on app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss